# Can I use a USB Wireless Adapter to receive WIFI 6 on an old laptop?

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11, usb-network-adapter

My apartment only provide WIFI 6 network. But my wireless network adapter driver version was around 2017.x, which is too old for WIFI 6. Plus the system version of my laptop is also too old, I cannot update the wireless network adapter driver to the latest version.

So I want to know if I can buy a USB Wireless Adapter which supports WIFI 6 to let my laptop connect to the WIFI 6 network successfully.

The product description is like: WiFi Nation WiFi 6 AX1800 2T2R, USB 3.0 Chipset: RTL8832AU, WiFi Dongle Adapter | 802.11ax Gigabit Wireless Network Card Adapter | 5GHz/2.4GHz | WPA3 Network Security | Windows 7/10/11

Comment: If your laptop doesn't have USB3.x ports and/or is running an unsupported and outdated OS then it probably won't work.

Comment: I very much doubt it is Wi-Fi 6 only. It will very likely also support anything down to 802.11a, the original 5 GHz band Wi-Fi. Please provide more details about the hardware involved.

Answer (score -1):

Yes a Wi-Fi 6 (802.11ax) USB adapter will work on any compatible version of Windows.

In this context any compatible version of Windows refers to any version of Windows the WiFi adapter is compatible with. Most USB adapters are compatible with Windows 7, 8, 8.1, and 10. Not all specify Windows 11 yet.